# RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, restore

I've managed to write a function that allows me to backup a SQL Server database, but I'm struggling with trying with restoring and using the backed up version.

My code:

```vb
    Try
        Dim confirmBackUp As MsgBoxResult
        confirmBackUp = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to restore?")

        If confirmBackUp = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then  Else Exit Sub
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
        con = New OleDbConnection()

             ' con.Connectionstring is read from an .ini file, but the string is correct

        con.Open()
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = "RESTORE DATABASE MaintenanceControl FROM DISK='c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\MaintenanceControl.bak'"
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MsgBox("Database Restored", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Success")
        con.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        errorLog(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace)
        MsgBox("Could not restore database, refer to error log")

    End Try
```

But on the `.ExecuteNonQuery()` line, I get the following error;

> RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
>
> RESTORE cannot process database 'MaintenanceControl' because it is in use by this session. It is recommended that the master database be used when performing this operation.

What is the issue? Is it because con is also the name of the connection to the live database and it shouldn't be given a new string?

**EDIT**

I've now set the `Initial Catalog` part of the connection to 'Master', as well as added con.Close() before `con = New OleDbconnection` however the error I now get is

> RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
> Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use.

Comment: Does your connection string point to the database MaintenanceControl too? Performing a restore on a database you're connected to might be the issue - the error message certainly seems to suggest so.

Comment: Have you tried `Use master;go;cmd.CommandText = "RESTORE DATABASE MaintenanceCo.....`?

Comment: @phillyd On opening the program, `con` points to the live version of MaintenanceControl, yeah

Comment: @artm Are there some quotes or something missing from there? Pasting it as is wants me to generate method stubs for Use and master

Comment: I think changing your connection string to point to the master database instead will likely allow you to restore MaintenanceControl.

Comment: @phillyd How is this done? Changing `Initial Catalog` to Master?

Comment: Yes - You would also need to have permission to connect to the master database with the credentials you're using (whether that be by SQL Server Authentication or Windows Authentication).

Comment: @phillyd Yeah the credentials are all fine - Using `Initial Catalog` as Master, I get a different error 'Exclusive access to the database could not be obtained as the database is already in use'?

Comment: If you're ok with dropping and recreating the database, you can use this statement, which will allow you to drop it: `alter database SomeDatabase set single_user with rollback immediate; drop database SomeDatabase;`, and then create the database from scratch as you need.

Comment: @JoeEnos What does dropping the database do? What effect?

Comment: @joe You're trying to overwrite an existing database with the contents of the backup file, right? Dropping the database will destroy the database so that there's no possibility that someone is connected to it while you're trying to restore. Then you create the database cleanly.

Comment: @JoeEnos Perfect, if you wanna post that as an answer I'll accept and upvote it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're ok with dropping and recreating the database, you can use this statement, which will allow you to drop it:

```
alter database MaintenanceControl set single_user with rollback immediate; 
drop database SomeDatMaintenanceControl base;
```

and then create the database from scratch as you need.

Dropping the database will destroy the database so that there's no possibility that someone is connected to it while you're trying to restore. Then you create the database cleanly.